# How to use the free monad with Future[M[_]]

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, free-monad, scala-cats

I have implemented a simple language for an ETL process using the free monad. When using `List` as input and output for both data fetching and storing, everything works fine. However I am using async libraries and work with `Future[List]`

common imports and definitions

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free._

sealed trait Ops[A]
type OpsF[A] = Free[Ops, A]
```

working with `List`

```
case class Fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int) extends Ops[List[Record]]
case class Store(recs: List[Record]) extends Ops[List[Response]]

def fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int): OpsF[List[Record]] = 
    liftF[Ops, List[Record]](Fetch(offset, amount))
def store(recs: List[Record]): OpsF[List[Response]] = 
    liftF[Ops, List[Response]](Store(recs))

def simpleEtl(offset: Int, amount: Int): Free[Ops, List[Response]]  = 
    fetch(offset, amount).flatMap(r => store(r))
```

not working with `Future[List]`

```
case class Fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int) extends Ops[Future[List[Record]]]
case class Store(recs: List[Record]) extends Ops[Future[List[Response]]]

def fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int): OpsF[Future[List[Record]]] = 
    liftF[Ops, Future[List[Record]]](Fetch(offset, amount))
def store(recs: List[Record]): OpsF[Future[List[Response]]] = 
    liftF[Ops, Future[List[Response]]](Store(recs))

// explicit types in case I am misunderstanding more than I think
def simpleEtl(offset: Int, amount: Int): Free[Ops, Future[List[Response]]] = 
fetch(offset, amount).flatMap { rf: Future[List[Record]] =>
  val getResponses: OpsF[Future[List[Response]]] = rf map { r: List[Record] =>
    store(r)
  }
  getResponses
}
```

as expected, the type returned from the `flatMap`/`map` is wrong - I am not getting `OpsF[Future]` but a `Future[OpsF]`

```
Error:(34, 60) type mismatch;
 found   :  scala.concurrent.Future[OpsF[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Response]]]]
(which expands to)  scala.concurrent.Future[cats.free.Free[Ops,scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]]]
 required: OpsF[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Response]]]
(which expands to)  cats.free.Free[Ops,scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]]
    val getResponses: OpsF[Future[List[Response]]] = rf map { r: List[Record] =>
```

my current workaround is to have `store` accept `Future[List[Record]]` and letting the interpreter map over the `Future`, but it feels clumsy.

The issue is not specific to `List` - e.g. `Option` would be useful as well.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there some sort of a monad transformer for this?

Comment: This seems like a typical pattern for a monad transformer, on a first look seems like Haskell has somehow a `FreeT`, couldn't find it in scalaz or cats though.

Comment: scalaz has `FreeT` since [7.2.0](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.FreeT).

Comment: Can I point you towards 47 degree's library aptly named http://47deg.github.io/fetch/ which will soon become a typelevel incubator? Mind you, I don't work for 47 degrees but it seems like this already has a solution for much of what you want to do.

Comment: yeah, fetch seems to be moving in the right direction, but right now looks like I would need to tweak it a lot for my needs like batching. Ill definitely keep an eye on it while it matures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The abstract data type `Ops` defines an algebra to *fetch* and to *store* multiple `Record`s. It describes two operations, but that's also the only thing the algebra should do. How the operations are actually executed, shouldn't matter at all to `Fetch` and `Store`, the only useful thing you expect is respectively a `List[Record]` and a `List[Response]`.

By making the expected result type of `Fetch` and `Store` a `Future[List[Record]]]`, you limit the possibilities how to interpret this algebra. Maybe in your tests, you don't want to connect asynchronously to a webservice or a database and just want to test with a `Map[Int, Result]` or `Vector[Result]`, but now you are required to return a `Future` which makes the tests more complex than they could be.

But saying that you don't need `ETL[Future[List[Record]]]` doesn't solve your question: you are using async libraries and you probably want to return some `Future`.

Starting with your first implementation :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.implicits._
import cats.free.Free

type Record = String
type Response = String

sealed trait EtlOp[T]
case class Fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int) extends EtlOp[List[Record]]
case class Store(recs: List[Record]) extends EtlOp[List[Response]]

type ETL[A] = Free[EtlOp, A]

def fetch(offset: Int, amount: Int): ETL[List[Record]] = 
  Free.liftF(Fetch(offset, amount))
def store(recs: List[Record]): ETL[List[Response]] = 
  Free.liftF(Store(recs))

def fetchStore(offset: Int, amount: Int): ETL[List[Response]] =
  fetch(offset, amount).flatMap(store)
```

But now we still have no `Future`s ? That's the job of our interpreter :

```
import cats.~>

val interpretFutureDumb: EtlOp ~> Future = new (EtlOp ~> Future) {
  def apply[A](op: EtlOp[A]): Future[A] = op match {
    case Store(records) => 
      Future.successful(records.map(rec => s"Resp($rec)"))
      // store in DB, send to webservice, ...
    case Fetch(offset, amount) =>
      Future.successful(List.fill(amount)(offset.toString))
      // get from DB, from webservice, ...
  }
}
```

With this interpreter (where of course you would replace `Future.successful(...)` with something more useful) we can get our `Future[List[Response]]` :

```
val responses: Future[List[Response]] = 
  fetchStore(1, 5).foldMap(interpretFutureDumb)

val records: Future[List[Record]] = 
  fetch(2, 4).foldMap(interpretFutureDumb)

responses.foreach(println)
// List(Resp(1), Resp(1), Resp(1), Resp(1), Resp(1))
records.foreach(println)
// List(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

But we can still create a different interpreter which doesn't return a `Future` :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import cats.Id

val interpretSync: EtlOp ~> Id = new (EtlOp ~> Id) {
  val records: ListBuffer[Record] = ListBuffer()
  def apply[A](op: EtlOp[A]): Id[A] = op match {
    case Store(recs) => 
      records ++= recs
      records.toList
    case Fetch(offset, amount) =>
      records.drop(offset).take(amount).toList
  }
}

val etlResponse: ETL[List[Response]] =
  for { 
    _       <- store(List("a", "b", "c", "d"))
    records <- fetch(1, 2)
    resp    <- store(records)
  } yield resp

val responses2: List[Response] = etlResponse.foldMap(interpretSync)
// List(a, b, c, d, b, c)
```

Comment: Ah, I see, makes perfect sense. Looks like I have been conceptually confusing the lifting definitions with the execution by the interpreter Thank you Peter.

Comment: @peter-neyens When we combine Algebra, can we combine two interpreters - one returning Id and other returning Future?

Comment: I am not sure in what way you want to combine two interpreters. You could always interpret a program twice, once to `Id` and once to `Future`.

Comment: Explained like a God!